# Dynamics CRM: How do I make a javascript function trigger every time a field/control on the form gains focus?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm on version 2016, if that matters.

I have a javascript function that I need called every time a field on the form gains focus.

My end goal is to make it so if a lookup field gains focus, the text is auto-highlighted so there's no need to click it again before editing.

I just need to know how to get a function called each time a field gains focus on the form and can take it from there. Thanks.

Comment: There's definitely no supported way to do it.  You could use jQuery to attach focus events to lookup controls, but you're probably going to have a really hard time with it because of the way 2016 forms don't display input fields until they gain focus. Also, it would be unsupported and could break with any update.

Comment: Why do something upon the actual field gaining focus?

Comment: How would I attach a focus event to a lookup control? Not sure how to reference the lookup in jQuery since I'm only used to referencing HTML tags/classes...

Comment: Nevermind, opened up F12 console log thing and found the classes/IDs/etc of the fields on the form. Am using those in my jQuery click function. Thanks.